# Python Multiprocessing: billiard vs multiprocessing

Tags: python, celery, python-multiprocessing, python-billiard

**Original problem:** using `celery` task queue, I want the processes in the process pool to use shared CUDA arrays ( i.e. instead of each process having its unique array, I want one array to be accessed by all the processes. This is safe because only reads are performed ). Pytorch's `torch.multiprocessing` library allows this and according to the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/multiprocessing.html), it is a simple drop-in replacement for `multiprocessing`.

`billiard` and `multiprocessing` seem to be two viable options for creating process pools. Currently, `celery`, the python task queue library, uses `billiard` over `multiprocessing` due to some **feature improvements**. Someone asked a question [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/celery-users/5Uq6cvHDxHM), but the answer is not really specific.

```
It backports changes from the Python 2.7 and 3.x. 
The current version is compatible with Py2.4 - 2.7 and falls back to multiprocessing for 3.x, 
the next version will only support 2.6, 2.7 and 3.x.
```

I need to replace `billiard` with `multiprocessing` in `celery`'s source code ( in order to use pytorch's multiprocessing library `torch.multiprocessing`), but would this be okay? What are the differences between `multiprocessing` and `billiard`?

Comment: Please describe the original problem instead of your attempted solution.

Comment: "but would this be okay" - I can assure that it will not be a drop-in replacement. `billiard` and `multiprocessing` are differs now **a lot**. I suggest you describe your original problem as @KlausD. proposed

Comment: @KlausD.
Added description of the original problem.

Comment: so, you want to init some variable before *fork*?

Comment: @georgexsh
yes, and I want the variable to be shared among all the processes. However, since variable is a GPU array and the language is Python, it is a little harder to use certain CUDA IPC API that would be available in C, but isn't in Python. The only way to do is rely on Pytorch's library which implements some CUDA API.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To those who are looking to replace `celery`'s `billiard` with `multiprocessing`**it is not possible** according to this [reply](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/5362#issuecomment-466862879) from celery's dev